# Setting background color style to an observable and using style binding

Tags: javascript, css, knockout.js

I am trying to set an observable with a specific background color that will be called in the views. I created my observable but now when i apply it to the style binding - nothing happens when i render the page.

Here is what i have:

```
self.color = ko.observable(data.color || '');
```

i have set in my data: `color:'background-color: #E91E63'`

my view:

```
<div class="info" data-bind="style: color"></div>
```

when i run the page the div is still white and didn't change colors - not sure where i could be going wrong.

Comment: always prefer have a class declared for styles and later use `css` binding . you should not create unnecessary dependency in viewmodel .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
 self.bg_color = ko.observable(data.color || 'red');
```

then in html.

```
 <div class="info" data-bind="style:{ 'background-color' :  $data.bg_color() }"></div>
```

Comment: in my case 'style:{ 'background-color' :  bg_color }' worked just fine. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Style binding is similar to style tag in html. you have to provide attribute whose value needs to be updated.

```
eg: style:{background:color}
```

Also you can check this [JSFiddle reference](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/w2mnvmtp/)